# How can i user Material UI in my react app written with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use Material UI components in my Typescript react app but i cannot find its @types module. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: All MUI types are importable form MUI package. There's no need to install them separately. You can import them like `import {Checkbox, CheckboxProps} from '@material-ui/core';` where `CheckboxProps` is a TS type for `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install the @material-ui/core package as normal and it should work.

`npm install @material-ui/core --save-dev`

otherwise:

[Types for Material UI is available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/material-ui)

simply use NPM for that:

`npm install @types/material-ui --save-dev`